# I'm a beginner at programming in python. I keep getting a typeError: object() takes no parameters and I don't know how to fix it. What should I do?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at programming in python. I keep getting a typeError: object() takes no parameters and I don't know how to fix it. What should I do?

## Here is my code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


class Rectangle(object):
    def _init_(self, height, width, color):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def add_height(self,h):
        self.height = self.height + h
        return(self.height)

    def add_width(self,w):
        self.width = self.width+w
        return(self.width)

    def drawRectangle(self):
        plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle(0,0), self.height, self.width, fc=self.color)
        plt.axis('scaled')
        plt.show()

bluerectangle = Rectangle(5, 3, 'blue')
#I get the error after I create the object bluerectangle
```

Comment: Add the full traceback. It will help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'object() takes no parameters' error when calling constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595007/how-to-fix-object-takes-no-parameters-error-when-calling-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` takes to underscores and not only one on each side.

So you need

```py
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width, color):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
...
```

Because the init method was not spelled correctly it was not overriding the init method of `object`, which explain why python was complaning that `object()` takes no parameter.